# Cross compile problem with libsndfile in QtCreator

Tags: qt

I can cross compile simple [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) Project from Windows (Qt Creator) to RPi, following [that](http://www.todopic.com.ar/foros/index.php?topic=41770.0).
How can I add [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) to my project?
I installed libsndfile to RPi then re-sync RPi<->PC with QtCrossTool. But then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure libsndfile is added to your toolchain libraries. Then to link it to your project add a -lsndfile flag or similar to your linker flags. You may also need to copy the libsndfile.so or similar to your raspberry pi to run the program.
If pkgconfig (bleh) is installed that is the recommended way of generating the linker flags.
Quoting [the FAQ](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/FAQ.html#Q008):

> The pkg-config program makes finding the correct compiler flag values
>   and library location far easier. During the installation of
>   libsndfile, a file named sndfile.pc is installed in the directory
>   ${libdir}/pkgconfig (ie if libsndfile is installed in /usr/local/lib,
>   sndfile.pc will be installed in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/).
>
> In order for pkg-config to find sndfile.pc it may be necessary to
>   point the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH in the right direction.
>
> ```
>     export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
> ```
>
> Then, to compile a C file into an object file, the command would be:
>
> ```
>     gcc `pkg-config --cflags sndfile` -c somefile.c
> ```
>
> and to link a number of objects into an executable that links against
>   libsndfile, the command would be:
>
> ```
>     gcc `pkg-config --libs sndfile` obj1.o obj2.o -o program
> ```